# Add title screen to video on upload to YouTube via API

Tags: php, video, youtube-api

I currently use the YouTube API to allow website users to upload their videos through the site straight to our YouTube channel (adding META data etc) at the time of upload.

Ideally we would like to dynamically add some sort of title, watermark, opening screen or an image to the beginning and / or the end of the video. Essentially we just need any method of adding something to the video which adds some form of branding to it (even if just a plain company name at the bottom).

The uploads are from internal users (i.e. secure and trusted) and there is not an excessive amount so I would be happy to upload to our server first (instead of straight to YouTube), manipulate the video then upload to YouTube.

The site runs PHP on a dedicated Linux / Apache server setup.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a really quick and easy one: [Invideo Programming](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2790636?hl=en). Invideo Programming lets you add a small logo to a corner of the video, or promote another video in a different corner, or both.

You can add this to the API via [the Channels resource as as `invideoPromotion` attribute](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/update). We recently [did a show on Google Developers Live](https://developers.google.com/live/shows/38132276-10001) explaining how to configure this on both the web UI as well as in the API. Check it out - I think this'll do what you need.

Comment: Fantastic, can't believe I missed this (I did look on the YouTube API docs), thank you